# Unusual error where thread is not getting created?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have the following Main program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /*checkParameters(argc,argv);*/

    if (pthread_create(&supplierid, NULL, &supplier, NULL) != 0);
        error("ERROR creating supply threads \n");

}

void *supplier () {

    printf("hello? \n"); 

    while (timeremaining >= 0) {


        printf("\n the stock is %d" , stock);
        printf("\n the supply ies %d", supply);

        timeremaining--;

        if (stock + supply > cap_max)
            stock = cap_max;
        else
            stock = stock + supply;

        sleep(0.1);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Ok well, 95% of the time I run this program I get Error creating supply thread. And it never prints hello. 
This makes no sense. It just 1 thread.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you should probably use [pthread_exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) or just return from `supplier` so that thread cleanup handlers and thread local data can be deallocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon after your `if` statement:

```
if (pthread_create(&supplierid, NULL, &supplier, NULL) != 0);
```

This means that the statement that appears to be nested within the `if` statement is not actually nested at all and will always execute regardless of the condition.  Specifically, C is interpreting your code to mean

```
if (pthread_create(&supplierid, NULL, &supplier, NULL) != 0)
    ; /* Do nothing */

error("ERROR creating supply threads \n");
```

To fix this, remove the stray semicolon.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Alessandroempire- No worries!  I've spent hours tracking down bugs like this before.  I think everyone who's written enough C code has done this.